# Como é feito esse efeito de hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É a fitinha colorida que se expande...

Comment: Esse efeito hover é bastante em animação de links, pode-se criar esses efeitos tanto com css quanto com javascript, pesquise um pouco amigo e você entenderá!

Comment: inova pixel, editei a pergunta colocando um `.gif` que filmei nesse site que tinhas indicado. Na proxima vêz podes fazer tu isso, ou tirar fotos do efeito que pretendes. Já conheces o site e como se deve criar e formatar uma boa pergunta...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O truque é usar `transform` associado ao pseudo elemento `:after` e com uma transição no zoom, tipo efeito lupa.

Algo assim:

```css
div {
    width: 150px;
}
div:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2e7061;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
div:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: transform 325ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div>Traz aqui o mouse!</div>
```